# How to dump/write multiple python dataframes to a text file keeping their header lines?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple pandas dataframes each with a different shape. 
Some dataframes have 2 lines of header lines, some have only 1 header line.
Each a different number of columns.

How to dump/write multiple python dataframes to a text file keeping their header lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this and it worked :

```
df1.to_csv(r"C:\Users\sb512911\Desktop\All\Applications\VDR\output\out.txt", sep = ' ', mode = 'a')

df2.to_csv(r"C:\Users\sb512911\Desktop\All\Applications\VDR\output\out.txt", sep = ' ', mode = 'a')
```

Please see if this works for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, I did in the old manner.
Without thinking in dataframes, I read file and write line by line.

Comment: great, but since you have asked for a way to write multiple python dataframe in a single text file, my answer does it exactly, and I put in effort to find a solution for you, so please accept my answer!